# Add a document type to a Mac OS X Project

Tags: xcode, import, export, document

My Mac application is not a document based application. That means you can have only one window open and you do not notice the saving of the data to a file in the library.

But now I want to import and export data.

I found it was not that hard, and the importing and exporting works well.

BUT: Not good enough. When you see the exported file in finder, you see it as an unknown file. And if you try to open it, you get the message that no application, not even my app can open it. You have to click "Import" In the App.

I want that you can see the file being part of my Application.

And if you click it, the application should show up and ask you if you want to import. I googled for it and I searched the preferences, but I did not find anything. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a UTI to your info.plist file so the Finder knows which app to open when you double click a file of your app's type.

I found this tutorial.  I don't think it's necessarily NSDocument specific.

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios

Comment: This person is building a mac osx application (me too!).  Does this answer apply to mac os x apps?  I will find out shortly, I guess!

Comment: @Ethan have you figure it out yet?